# How to define a recursive Iterable type?

Tags: type-hinting, mypy, python-3.9

I am trying to define a recursive Iterable type `Iterable_of_TOIs`:

```
# from __future__ import annotations
from typing import overload, Optional, Iterable, Union


class ToI:
    """
    ToI = Token or Iterable of ToIs
    """
    Iterable_of_ToIs = Iterable[Union[ToI, 'Iterable_of_ToIs']]

    @overload
    def __init__(self, *, token: str) -> None:
        ...

    @overload
    def __init__(self, *, iterable: Iterable_of_ToIs) -> None:
        ...

    # actual implementation
    def __init__(
            self,
            token: Optional[str] = None,
            iterable: Optional[Iterable_of_ToIs] = None
    ) -> None:
        self.token: Optional[str] = token
        self.iterable: Optional[Iterable_of_ToIs] = iterable
```

But mypy complains

- with `error: Name 'Iterable_of_ToIs' is not defined` or
- with `error: Cannot resolve name "Iterable_of_ToIs" (possible cyclic definition)` 
  if I move the definition of `Iterable_of_ToIs` out of the class scope.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Methods can never peek into the class scope. Method-local annotations are no exception for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I am doing wrong not that much.

Regarding `error: Name 'Iterable_of_ToIs' is not defined`:
in the section *Motivation* of [PEP 613](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0613/) (Status `Accepted`) I found:

> Type aliases are declared as top level variable assignments.

Yikes! Couldn't find this rule for Python 3.9 or prior in any other doc, especially not in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

But anyway... it explains the error. So, ok, let's move the line to the top level.

Regarding `error: Cannot resolve name "Iterable_of_ToIs" (possible cyclic definition)`:
seems to be not yet supported: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/731